# How can I echo an alias that needs to contain embedded quotes?

Tags: bash

I use these aliases a lot:

```bash
alias gd='git diff'
alias gst='git status'
alias gco='git checkout'
alias gcb='git checkout -b'
alias gitlogonelinepretty='git log --pretty=format:%C(yellow)%h %Cred%ad %Cblue%an %Cgreen%s --date=short'
```

I would like to use those aliases in a docker container. I am writing those aliases to **~/.bashrc** like so:

```bash
echo alias gd=\'git diff\' >> ~/.bashrc
echo alias gst=\'git status\' >> ~/.bashrc
echo alias gco=\'git checkout\' >> ~/.bashrc
echo alias gcb=\'git checkout -b\' >> ~/.bashrc
echo alias gitlogonelinepretty=\'git log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h %Cred%ad %Cblue%an %Cgreen%s" --date=short\' >> ~/.bashrc
```

They all work apart from the last one and its because of the embedded quotes. I'll demonstrate. If I issue this command in bash:

`echo \'git log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h %Cred%ad %Cblue%an %Cgreen%s" --date=short\'`

it echoes this:

> 'git log --pretty=format:%C(yellow)%h %Cred%ad %Cblue%an %Cgreen%s --date=short'

[image: screenshot of echo and its output]

As you can see, the quotes (") have been stripped out.

I have attempted to escape them like so:

`echo \'git log --pretty=format:\"%C(yellow)%h %Cred%ad %Cblue%an %Cgreen%s\" --date=short\'`

but that causes an error:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

[image]

How can I modify this echo command so that the output still includes the quotes?

Comment: Why not put them in `.bashrc.additions` and then do `cat .bashrc.additions >> .bashrc`?

Comment: nice idea. I will give it a go. Though I'm intrigued to know whether this is solvable by amending the `echo`

Comment: Great! You're welcome!  Re: _"I'm intrigued to know whether this is solvable by amending the `echo`"_ - Sure, I added an answer for that along with my suggestion to prepare a file.

Comment: you can use my [mquote](https://github.com/clarkwang/magic-aliases) to get what's in the accepted answer. see https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k6Bf.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve it by single-quoting the whole thing:

```bash
echo 'alias gitlogonelinepretty='\''git log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h %Cred%ad %Cblue%an %Cgreen%s" --date=short'\''' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Note the sequence `'\''` to embed a single `'` in the single-quoted string.

A simpler solution would be to prepare the whole thing in a separate file, `.bashrc.additions`, and then append the whole thing:

```bash
cat .bashrc.additions >> .bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash is complaining because you have unescaped special characters (the parentheses) and it doesn't understand the resulting command line. You need to escape everything it might interpret specially. The easiest way to do this is wrap things you don't want interpreted in single quotes.

```
#                              V ------  unescaped single quotes   ------- V
echo \'git log --pretty=format:'"%C(yellow)%h %Cred%ad %Cblue%an %Cgreen%s"' --date=short\'
# prints 'git log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h %Cred%ad %Cblue%an %Cgreen%s" --date=short'
```

The unescaped single quotes will tell bash to treat the things between them literally, then bash will remove them and leave you with just the string you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have those aliases, why not just use the alias expansion to populate your new file instead of hard-coding it again with an echo:

```
$ alias gitlogonelinepretty='git log --pretty=format:%C(yellow)%h %Cred%ad %Cblue%an %Cgreen%s --date=short'

$ alias gitlogonelinepretty > file

$ cat file
alias gitlogonelinepretty='git log --pretty=format:%C(yellow)%h %Cred%ad %Cblue%an %Cgreen%s --date=short'
```

If you do need to hard-code it for some reason then consider either of these:

```
$ printf 'alias gitlogonelinepretty=%q\n' 'git log --pretty=format:%C(yellow)%h %Cred%ad %Cblue%an %Cgreen%s --date=short'
alias gitlogonelinepretty=git\ log\ --pretty=format:%C\(yellow\)%h\ %Cred%ad\ %Cblue%an\ %Cgreen%s\ --date=short

$ printf "alias gitlogonelinepretty='%s'\n" 'git log --pretty=format:%C(yellow)%h %Cred%ad %Cblue%an %Cgreen%s --date=short'
alias gitlogonelinepretty='git log --pretty=format:%C(yellow)%h %Cred%ad %Cblue%an %Cgreen%s --date=short'
```